# how to make polygons made on my image clickable using canvas js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

```
var b = {
  "vertices": [
  [{ "x": 15, "y": 5 }, { "x": 28, "y": 2 }, { "x": 37, "y": 49 }, { "x": 24, "y": 51 }],
  [{ "x": 106, "y": 5 }, { "x": 252, "y": 3 }, { "x": 252, "y": 36 }, { "x": 106, "y": 38 }],
  [{ "x": 16, "y": 40 }, { "x": 296, "y": 41 }, { "x": 296, "y": 100 }, { "x": 16, "y": 99 }],
  [{ "x": 26, "y": 123 }, { "x": 255, "y": 124 }, { "x": 255, "y": 239 }, { "x": 26, "y": 238 }],
  [{ "x": 106, "y": 376 }, { "x": 255, "y": 375 }, { "x": 255, "y": 393 }, { "x": 106, "y": 394 }]]
};
```

Polygon draw function for drawing the above coordinates in canvas js:

```
function drawpolygon() {
  for (i = 0; i < ar.vertices.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
      cx.beginPath();
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][0].x, ar.vertices[i][0].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][1].x, ar.vertices[i][1].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][2].x, ar.vertices[i][2].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][3].x, ar.vertices[i][3].y);

      if (j == 3) {
        cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][0].x, ar.vertices[i][0].y);
      }

      cx.strokeStyle = "red";
      cx.lineWidth = "1.5";
      cx.stroke();
      cx.closePath();
    }
  }
}
```

i have drawn the polygons using the canvas js. How to make these clickable? Hitregion is outdated..

Comment: You should check if it intersects with the rendered object by confronting mouse and shape positions

Comment: Are the polygons drawn convex or concave or a mix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage [`Canvas​Rendering​Context2D.isPoint​InPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath).  It will allow you to determine if a given point is within either the "current" stateful path or if a point is in a `Path2D` object if you use those instead.

Try clicking within the rendered polygons below.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const cx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var ar = {
  "vertices": [
  [{ "x": 15, "y": 5 }, { "x": 28, "y": 2 }, { "x": 37, "y": 49 }, { "x": 24, "y": 51 }],
  [{ "x": 106, "y": 5 }, { "x": 252, "y": 3 }, { "x": 252, "y": 36 }, { "x": 106, "y": 38 }],
  [{ "x": 16, "y": 40 }, { "x": 296, "y": 41 }, { "x": 296, "y": 100 }, { "x": 16, "y": 99 }],
  [{ "x": 26, "y": 123 }, { "x": 255, "y": 124 }, { "x": 255, "y": 239 }, { "x": 26, "y": 238 }],
  [{ "x": 106, "y": 376 }, { "x": 255, "y": 375 }, { "x": 255, "y": 393 }, { "x": 106, "y": 394 }]]
};

function drawpolygon(e) {
  let x, y;

  // Only try to hit detect if there was a click
  if (e) {
    // Localize the click to within the canvas
    const {clientX, clientY, currentTarget} = e;
    const {left, top} = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = clientX - left;
    y = clientY - top;
  }

  // Clear the canvas
  cx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Iterate all the polygons
  for (i = 0; i < ar.vertices.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {

      cx.beginPath();
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][0].x, ar.vertices[i][0].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][1].x, ar.vertices[i][1].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][2].x, ar.vertices[i][2].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][3].x, ar.vertices[i][3].y);

      if (j == 3) {
        cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][0].x, ar.vertices[i][0].y);
      }

      cx.closePath();

      // Paint green if the click was in the path, red otherwise
      cx.strokeStyle = cx.isPointInPath(x, y) ? "green" : "red";
      cx.lineWidth = "1.5";
      cx.stroke();
    }
  }
}

// Draw immediately for reference
drawpolygon();
// Draw again whenever we click
canvas.addEventListener("click", drawpolygon);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Sneha Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Did you update your `drawpolygon` method based on my answer?

Comment: @Sneha What do you mean?

Comment: @Sneha What are you expecting to happen?  Is the "inner" polygon considered a "hole" in the "outer" polygon?  If that is the case, you'll need to adjust how you define polygons such that a polygon with a hole is one polygon definition.  I believe that's what the `fillRule` of the function is for.

Comment: how to leave the clicked polygon left stroked green